# javascript declaring key value pair in a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

let us say i have a object in which there is a function and inside the function i have declared some key values.
if every function is an function object in javascript then it is totally legal to declare key value pair in it.

```
var a ={
  a: "shiv",
  b: "shiv1",
  c: function(){
    L:"shiv1",
    console.log(L);
  }
}
```

how can i access these keys. in what scenarios i need to add key value pairs to a function. what does this signify. For Example in this function, how can i access L key.

Edit 1: 
Console.log line will through err.
let say we have only this code

```
var a ={
  a: "shiv",
  b: "shiv1",
  c: function(){
    L:"shiv1",
  }
}
```

what does declaring a key in function signify. if i need to access L key how can i

Comment: No, even if functions are objects, you can't just do `key : value` anywhere, it would have to be `this.key = value` otherwise you're just creating a label. Also, case matters.

Answer (score 1):

You every function is also an object, meaning that you can indeed set properties to it. In fact every function has `length` property, which denotes the number of formal arguments this function accepts.

However the syntax you are using to set function properties is not how you should do it. Even though you are using perfectly valid syntax, this is [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), not property definition syntax. If you wanted to set a property to a function object in your case you would do it like this:

```
function c() {
  console.log(c.L) // => "I'm a property of c function"
}
c.L = "I'm a property of c function";

var a = {
  a: "shiv",
  b: "shiv1",
  c: c
}
```

When it can be useful? Like I said there is a limited use for it, like `length` property of the function, but in many cases you would not need setting properties on a function level directly.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be throwing errors:

```
L:"shiv1",
console.log(l);
```

You probably want:

```
  c: function(){
    return {L:"shiv1"};
  }
```

And then access it as:

```
a.c().L;
```

---

Full example here:

```js
var a ={
  a: "shiv",
  b: "shiv1",
  c: function(){
    return {L:"shiv1"}    
  }
}

alert(a.c().L);
```

Comment: *"This has to be throwing errors:"* actually this is perfectly valid syntax (but of course, no trailing `,`), probably why OP is confused in the first place thinking that it actually sets property.

Comment: that is very right. this will throw err. But what you are proposing is returning an object then access the particular property of that object. but i just want to ask what does declaring a key L in the function signify and what is its use case scenario.

Comment: @dfsq `l` will be undefined there, the rest could pass validation as a label, even with that comma.

Comment: @shivgarg Not sure I understood. What are you trying to accomplish here? Modify the function context?

Comment: Of course, because `l` is undefined indeed. But I'm saying that `L:"shiv1"` is valid and means something.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare keys like you did inside the function.
This doesn't work:

```
c: function(){
    L:"shiv1", //Declaration don't work in this context
    console.log(l); //Don't work
}
```

Try this (Please, remove the "function" statement):

```
c: {
 L:"shiv1"
}
```

Also, you can do this:

```
c: function() {
    var test = "shiv1";
    return test;
}
```

If you want to work with parameters:

```
c: function(a, b) {
    var test = a + " shiv1 " + b;
    return test;
}
```

Or:

```
c: function(a, b) {
    var total = a + b;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Why you can't do this inside a function like you had done, what you can do it's as someone had said in a comment before: {L : "shiv1" }. Or, you can use a variable as I commented.

Comment: i am just asking, what does this mean or signify. is this any use case of this declaration

Comment: So, what I know it's in this case {L:"shiv1"} is an object and you can use for many purposes. But pay attention because JSON declaration is very similar. May this link will help you a lot [link]http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/objects. Also, you can use objects to group functions like a class. L:"shiv1" It's not exactly wrong, only in that context where you had used. I hope that helps you, I don't know if it is what you are looking for.